# Formatting UICollectionViewCell inner items with constraints

Tags: swift, constraints, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UICollectionViewCell and I want to be able to format the items inside of it more freely. That means - I want to be able to set constraints relative to the cell itself.

This is my cell:

[image: My UICollectionViewCell]

And this is my code:

```
//image View Constraints
        let productImageTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductImageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 1) // constant was 10
        let productImageBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductImageView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -30)
        let productImageLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductImageView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let productImageTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductImageView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)

        //product name field constraints
        let productNameTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductName, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: ProductImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let productNameBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductName, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let productNameLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductName, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let productNameTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductName, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

What I want:

1. The ImageView to be closer to the cell's top edge
2. The product name label to be in the center
3. To be able to add another label between the product name label and the cell's bottom edge

How do I do that ? How do I take into account the cell's edges ?

Comment: Do you want this programmatically or Using Xib it is ok ?

Comment: Programmatically . I am rather new to Xcode/Swift so I don't know how to use Xib, or even what it is :)

Comment: Xib use is very easy to use rather than programmatically.

Comment: Follows this link will help you: http://www.seemuapps.com/tutorial-uicollectionview-with-custom-cell

Comment: I am not using the interface builder. This code is shared among many views, so I have to keep it programatically

Comment: So XIB is the visual interface I see in Main.storyboard ? If so, I don't want it in XIB :)

Comment: If your multiple collection view contains same UI then you can also create and share XIB among all collection view.

Comment: I prefer to use it programatically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Layout Anchors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor) to achieve this.
 first get the margins of your `UICollectionViewCell` contentView like below

```
let margins = self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
```

**1. The ImageView to be closer to the cell's top edge**

Add following constraints relative to cell's content view margins like below

```
//Add top, left, right constraint relative to cell content view like below

yourImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor,constant:5).isActive = true
yourImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leftAnchor,constant:5).isActive = true
yourImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.rightAnchor,constant:5).isActive = true
```

**2. The product name label to be in the center**

```
//To center align
yourLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
//Now set your label top anchor to display it below your image view

yourLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourImageView.bottomAnchor,constant:5).isActive = true
```

**3. To be able to add another label between the product name label and the cell's bottom edge**

```
anotherLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourLabel.bottomAnchor,constant:5).isActive = true
anotherLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
//To center align
anotherLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

**UPDATE**

Make sure you have added your control as subview and set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

The order in which you should add constraint programmatically is as follows

1. Initialise your controls like `let yourLabel = UILabel()`
2. Set `yourLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
3. Add your label as subview `self.addSubView(yourLabel)`
4. Add constraints to your label

Comment: 1) This is working, but it shrunk my image. I want it to stay the same. I tried changing the constans in left and right anchors, it doesn't seem to work.

2) This is working fine !
3) This throws an exception

Comment: for 1) try adding a height anchor and set image view contentMode property to `imgview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`, for 3) what exception?

Comment: To be honest, I can't see what exception. I am using Mac on VM, and on exception it usually logs me off from the Mac, and I need to re-login, and then the debugger view has no information in it... :/

Comment: make sure the label is added as a subview to the contentView before adding constraints.

Comment: I had it backwards. I first added constraints and then the labels and image. It did work with the image and name label tho. Let me swap them

Comment: As of right now, my code is exactly like you wrote in your comment, along with the .scaleAspectFit property. It throws an exception. I am trying to do this multiple times until I see the exception type

Comment: try commenting out code that throws exception until you find the exact line where it is breaking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166298/discussion-between-ofri-and-fahadsk).

Answer (score 1):

1

```
let productImageTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductImageView,
                                                   attribute: .top,
                                                   relatedBy: .equal,
                                                   toItem: self,
                                                   attribute: .top,
                                                   multiplier: 1,
                                                   constant: 1) <- make it 0 so it will be pinned to top edge
```

2 Set ProductName.textAlignment = .center

3 a) Remove productNameBottomConstraint so ProductName's height will be calculated from text and font automatically

b) Add another label with layout

```
let productName2TopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductName2, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: ProductName, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
let productName2BottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductName2, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let productName2LeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductName2, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
let productName2TrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductName2, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

Comment: 1) I changed constant to "0" and it is not pinned to top edge. Actually, it stays the same.
2) worked!
3) I get an exception

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000285690 V:

Comment: 1 I can assume the image size is less than imageViewFrame, 3 ProductName2 must be on the same level as ProductName (subviews of the same view)

Comment: 1) I'm not sure how to check this.
2) They are. Two labels in the same cell

Comment: 1 ProductImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill, 2 show how you addSubview for ProductName and ProductName2

Comment: self.bringSubview(toFront: ProductImageView)
        self.bringSubview(toFront: ProductName)
        self.bringSubview(toFront: ProductPrice)

Comment: And I was using ProductImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit